# Связка PHP + PYTHON

Tags: php, python

Есть идея использования связки двух языков для одного проекта и разных задач.

1.PHP будет взаимодейстсовать с пользователем. Получать от него данные и частино обрабатывать.Отвечать за вывод контента.Возможно обращаться к другому языку иногда.

2.PYTHON.Демоны,воркеры и другое что будет работать в стороне.С юзером не будет иметь дел в основном.

Насколько будет адекватная данная связка/имеет она место на жизнь?

Comment: PHP часть тоже вполне возможно написать на Python (что и рекомендую).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом нет ничего страшного.
Часто приходится "дружить" разные сервисы и платформы.

Для этого используется [микросервисная архитектура](http://lab.nitec.kz/wiki/index.php/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)

**Cтоит определиться co способом взаимодействия**

Для php/python лучшим вариантом будет [REST](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) API.

Еще возможные варианты:

1. [SOAP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)
2. взаимодействие через общую БД ( один из вариантов этого подхода по
   [ссылке](http://www.moluch.ru/archive/56/7601/) )
3. Через файлы ( этот подход оправдан, если ключевая логика завязана на
   обработке и передаче файлов, но все же стоит подумать еще немного
   больше прежде чем использовать эту связь )

**Для реализации демонов** на python можно использовать [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). Достаточно удобная и простая обертка для демонизации

Answer (score 1):

Связка очень плохая, т.к.:

1. автору необходимо постоянно держать актуальный код для обоих языков;
2. не будет использован мощнейший потенциал выбранного языка программирования: повторная используемость кода, т.к. можно заложить уже готовые структуры данных для движков обоих систем.

Answer (score 1):

Почему, не стоит? Во-первых это опыт, который может пригодится со временем. Во-вторых, как бы не нахваливали скорость PHP 7, он всё же остаётся "сборщиком" страниц сайта: хоть кроме этого он еще много чего умеет, но собирает страницы он просто виртуозно. Теперь Python, его универсальность в сравнении с PHP не вызывает сомнений + огромное количество готовых библиотек, + он умеет работать со многими API приложений, причём без танцев с бубном: скорее всего, уже кто то заморочился и написал библиотеку. Попробуй то же самое сделать на PHP.